# How can I filter data frame rows and save the sum in new row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

- I would like to combine all the rows the have a score column less than 63,
- Then take some of all of them and save them in a new row we can call it 'new sum' it will be the sum of all scores that have a score less than or equal to 63.
- drop that columns contain values less than 63.
- I am using a panda.
- Please see the attached picture

[image: Here is the data frame, click me]

Answer (score 1):

You can do so as follows:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['Other', "", df[df['Score'] < 63]['Score'].sum(), ""]
```

If you want to remove the rows having `Score` < 63, you can do so as follows:

```
df.drop(df[df['Score'] < 63].index, inplace=True)
```

**Note:** The option, `inplace=True` changes the `DataFrame` permanently. If you do not want the change to be applied to the `DataFrame` permanently, omit this option e.g.

```
new_df = df.drop(df[df['Score'] < 63].index)
```

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Alisa', 'Bobby', 'Cathrine', 'Alisa', 'Bobby', 'Cathrine', 'Alisa', 'Bobby', 'Cathrine', 'Alisa', 'Bobby',
             'Cathrine'],
    'Subject': ['Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Science', 'Science', 'Science', 'History', 'History',
                'History', 'Economics', 'Economics', 'Economics'],
    'Score': [62, 47, 55, 74, 31, 77, 85, 63, 42, 62, 89, 85],
    'score-ranked': [7.5, 10.0, 9.0, 5.0, 12.0, 4.0, 2.5, 6.0, 11.0, 7.5, 1.0, 2.5]
})

df.loc[len(df)] = ['Other', "", df[df['Score'] < 63]['Score'].sum(), ""]

df.drop(df[df['Score'] < 63].index, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        Name    Subject  Score score-ranked
3      Alisa    Science     74          5.0
5   Cathrine    Science     77          4.0
6      Alisa    History     85          2.5
7      Bobby    History     63          6.0
10     Bobby  Economics     89          1.0
11  Cathrine  Economics     85          2.5
12     Other               299
```

Comment: Hi there, I did not mean for you to delete your answer :-) I see that you answer regex questions sometimes (which is awesome), and I only wanted to give some suggestions.

Comment: @Thefourthbird - Thanks for the encouraging words as always. Somehow, I saw your comment only after deleting my answer. The reason why I deleted my answer was that I was not satisfied with my answer :). By the way, the solution you have posted in the comment is awesome; please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas built-in `Fancy indexing`:

```
df = df[df['score'] < 30]
df.loc[len(df.index)] = ["TOTAL","",sum(df['score']),""]
```

Comment: I would like to do something else, not df[df['Score'] > 63]

Comment: Check if that's what you want

Comment: Thank you, Pedro, actually, it is part of what I want and  it is work but also I want to combine all of them and remove anything less than 63

Comment: Try the code now

Answer (score 0):

Try
df[df['Score'] > 63]
df.groupby(['Name'])[Score].sum()
i am writing it as answer because i can't comment

Comment: Thank you Faika, but it does not work, I want to combine and drop at the same time.