# if column years is >=10, user personal details should be replaced with his id (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I am new to pandas.

Here I am iterating through each row and checking the exit date of a user if his exit date is >= 10 his personal details should be replaced with his id.

I am stuck please help.

```
for edate in pd.to_datetime(df1['EXIT_DATE']):

    rdelt = relativedelta(datetime.today(),edate)

    df1['years'] = rdelt.years

    # its modifying each row in a DataFrame.
    #df1.loc[flag,['first_name','middel_name','email']] = df1['user_id']
```

Comment: Please add a small example input dataframe and the expected output, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples and [mcve].

Comment: `df.loc[df['EXIT_DATE'] >= 10, ['first_name','middel_name','email']] = df1['user_id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below to avoid the loop:

```
# Ensure EXIT_DATE dtype is a datetime64
df1['EXIT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EXIT_DATE'])

df1['years'] = pd.Timestamp.today().year - df1['EXIT_DATE'].dt.year
df1.loc[df1['years'] >= 10, ['first_name','middle_name','email']] = df['user_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

+++++++++++++++++++

EDIT:

Added [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788714/how-can-i-filter-data-frame-rows-and-save-the-sum-in-new-row/69790091#69790091) to an answer from @Arvind Kumar Avinash explaining "Filtering on dataframe"

++++++++++++++++++++

Taking @Emi OB comment and adding explanation;

You can create a flag/mask by using the usual "<,>,<=,>=" operators e.g

```py
age = pd.Series([20,23,22,19,30])
age>22 # Series([False,True,False,False,True])
```

thus you can use that mask to operate on all the `True` indexes i.e if we want to replace all the `age` where `age>22` (i.e all the index' where we have the `True` value) with the value `22`, we do it simply by

```py
age = pd.Series([20,23,22,19,30])
mask = age>22 # Series([False,True,False,False,True])
age.loc[mask] = 22
age # pd.Series([20,22,22,19,22])
```

the exact same logic can be used on data-frames

Comment: Very good explanation! Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790091/10819573) for an example on `DataFrame`.

Comment: Agreed - added the link to the answer